# How to update the selected source indices programmatically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, selection, bokeh

From the docs, the [`Selection`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/selections.html#bokeh.models.selections.Selection) object says:

> Selections are typically created by selecting points in a plot with a SelectTool, but can also be programmatically specified.

But I do not how to set some selected points programmatically. For example if I want to update the selection by clicking on some button. I can update the element `source.selected.indices`, but the event is not triggered and the points are not marked as selected

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models.tools import LassoSelectTool, TapTool
from bokeh.models.widgets.buttons import Button

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
))

p = figure(
    plot_height=300,
    tools='',
)
p.circle( x='x', y='y', size=20, source=source)

lasso_select = LassoSelectTool(
    select_every_mousemove=False,
)
tap = TapTool()
tools = (lasso_select, tap)
p.add_tools(*tools)

def update_selection_programmatically():
    source.selected.update(indices=[4])           # the indices attribute is updated but the figure is not repainted, some event is not triggered.
                                                  # So the points are not marked as selected
bt = Button(
    label="Update Selection",
    button_type="success",
    width=50
)

bt.on_click(update_selection_programmatically)


def update_selection(attr, old, new):
    print('>> NEW SELECTION: {}'.format(new.indices))
    # new.indices = [0]       # this works fine here

source.on_change('selected', update_selection)

curdoc().add_root(column([p, bt]))
```

The indices attribute is updated but the figure is not repainted.

Comment: Seems like a bug, I would suggest a GH issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer update

Finally bokeh developers solved the issue. Now the indices can be updated with

```
source.selected.update(indices=[4])

# or equivalently

source.selected.indices = [4]
```

### Old Workaround

[johncthomas wrote a comment in the GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7944#issuecomment-411162617). There is a workaround:

> I figured out a work around for this
>
> ```
> # When this does not update the visible selections 
> source.selected.indices = new_indicies
>
> # This causes the selections to be visible
> source.data = source.data
> ```
>
> Specifically this is when running a server in version 13.0. Obviously not ideal but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This works with a CustomJS callback

```
bt.callback = CustomJS(args={'source':source},code="""source.selected.indices = [4];source.change.emit();""")
```

I think Python callbacks are supposed to do the source.change.emit() automatically, so not sure why yours is not working.
But you can do it explicitly in a JS callback.

And I don't know why but it does not trigger update_selection

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Anyway I have written an [GH issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7944). Let´s see what happens